# Angularjs+Typescript directive implementing $compile

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

I am having issues injecting $compile in the following directive.

```
export class Element {
    public link(scope:dirScopeInterface, element:any, attrs:ng.IAttributes, formCtrl:ng.IFormController) {
        var attr = this.arrayJoiner(scope.standard, scope.attrs || {}, scope.ignore || {});
        element.html(this.compiler(attr));
        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
}
```

At the moment it is throwing an $compile is undefined error. I have tried using

```
static $inject = ['$compile'];
```

But it disappears from the transpiled script for some reason.

[Here](http://typescript.io/ghIYTr1w0gg) is the full code used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a way to get it to work but it is not as elegant as I would have liked.

```
angular.module('formDirectives', [], function($compileProvider){
    $compileProvider.directive('catElement', ($compile) => {
        return new Element($compile);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 9):

Include the `static $inject` and a `constructor`:

```
export class Element {

    // $compile can then be used as this.$compile
    constructor(private $compile: ng.ICompileService){};

    public link(scope:dirScopeInterface, element:any, attrs:ng.IAttributes, formCtrl:ng.IFormController) {
        var attr = this.arrayJoiner(scope.standard, scope.attrs || {}, scope.ignore || {});
        element.html(this.compiler(attr));
        this.$compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

To register this directive with angular, this is what I always do (there are multiple solutions):

```
export class Element implements angular.IDirective {

    public static ID = "element";

    // This can then be removed:
    // static $inject = ["$compile"];

    // ..

    /**
     * The factory function that creates the directive
     */
    static factory(): angular.IDirectiveFactory {
        const directive = ($compile) => new Element($compile);
        directive.$inject = ["$compile"];
        return directive;
    }
}
```

and to register:

```
angular.module("myModule" [])
    .directive(Element.ID, Element.factory());
```

Comment: How would I register this directive with angular then as the constructor requires a parameter? Also I have implemented it the way you specified but am getting an $compile is not a function error.

Comment: Angular uses dependency injection, so the constructor will resolve itself. You have to use the pointer to the controller to get to the private $compile variable: `this.$compile`

Comment: It looks like tho following:
    static $inject = ['$compile'];
        constructor(private $compile:ng.ICompileService){}
        public link = (scope:dirScopeInterface, element:any, attrs:ng.IAttributes, formCtrl:ng.IFormController) => {
            scope.tempForm = formCtrl;
            var attr = this.arrayJoiner(scope.standard, scope.attrs || {}, scope.ignore || {});
            element.html(this.compiler(attr));
            this.$compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
Angular throws an $compile not a function error.

Comment: I've added how I always register such typescript directives

Comment: @devqon: Where do I find `Directive`, to use in `new Directive`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it should be `new Element()`

Answer (score 0):

my implementation for jQuery Wizard Steps with AngularJS + Typescripts

It should work well for other `$compile` function too.

## AppDirective.ts

```
 export class stepwizard implements ng.IDirective {
    constructor() {
        console.log("construtor step wizard directive");
    }

    link($scope: ng.IScope, $element: JQuery, attributes: ng.IAttributes, ngModel: ng.INgModelController, ctrl: any) {
        console.log("start step wizard link function");
        $element.wrapInner('<div class="steps-wrapper">');
        const steps = $element.children(".steps-wrapper").steps({
            headerTag: "h3",
            bodyTag: "section",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
            autoFocus: true
        });
        const compiled = ctrl.$compile(steps);
    }

    public static Factory() {
        var directive = () => {
            return new stepwizard();
        };

        directive.$inject = ['$compile'];
        console.log("initial step wizard");

        return directive;
    }
}
```

## AppController.ts

```
    export class pageController{
    // your declaraction
    static $inject: Array<string> = [
      $compile',
    ];
    constructor(
      $compile: ng.ICompileService,
    ) {
    // your constructor declaraction
    }
```

## HTML

```
// sample take from official website
             <div stepwizard>
                <h3>Keyboard</h3>
                <section>
                    <p>Try the keyboard navigation by clicking arrow left or right!</p>
                </section>
                <h3>Effects</h3>
                <section>
                    <p>Wonderful transition effects.</p>
                </section>
                <h3>Pager</h3>
                <section>
                    <p>The next and previous buttons help you to navigate through your content.</p>
                </section>
            </div>

directives.stepwizard = <namespace>.directives.stepwizard.Factory();
app.directive(directives);
```