# TypeScript AngularJS directive for compile?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, angularjs-compile, angularjs-config

How do I implement this in AngularJS 1.5.4 with TypeScript 1.6.2?

Here is the vanilla JavaScript version from the official docs: [$compile#example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#example)

I've found this, but it doesn't work: [Angularjs+Typescript directive implementing $compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728464/angularjstypescript-directive-implementing-compile)

Here lies my current attempt:

```
export class Element implements angular.IDirective {
  public static ID = 'element';

  static $inject = ['$compile'];

  static factory(): angular.IDirectiveFactory {
    const directive = ($compile: ng.ICompileService) => new Element($compile);
    directive.$inject = Element.$inject;
    return directive;
  }

  constructor(private $compile: ng.ICompileService) {
  };

  link(scope: ng.IScope, element: any, attrs: any) {
    return scope.$watch(
      (scope: ng.IScope) => scope.$eval(attrs.compile),
      (value: string) => {
        element.html(value);
        this.$compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
    );
  }

  link_old_attempt(scope: any, element: any, attrs: ng.IAttributes,
                   formCtrl: ng.IFormController) {
    const attr = scope.standard || scope.attrs || scope.ignore;
    element.html(this.$compile(attr));
    this.$compile(element.contents())(scope);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide your code? I am using the same syntax as in the article which you provided and it works as expected.

Comment: Can you trace `Directive` in your IDE to find where it is? - Maybe I need to import it.

Comment: Do not have any pure "Directive" in my solution... Maybe you are registering it incorrectly? In my solution i have separate module ts file and i import directive ts and then register it.

Comment: Hmm, not sure where I was getting `Directive`. Anyway, I've updated the question with my latest attempt.

Comment: Looks correct. Can you also provide code how you register it?
Couple of notes:
1) you shouldn't return anything from link function.
2) Change your link function to lambda cause in other case you could have problems with 'this' context.
Like this: link = (..) => {..}